# Scrolling a div with scrollbar selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In Instagram direct there is such a div with all users, but it loads partly, and to load it completely we need to scroll down the scrollbar, but I cant find a way to do it. Any ideas?

I tried to send pg.down/end keys to the div but it didnt result

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to scroll a part of the page (side menu, popup, etc) is to get the list of elements contained in there, and then scroll to the last element using javascript.

```
contacts = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[style*='overflow: hidden auto']>div>div")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center"});', contacts[-1])
```